# How do I read an input file with colons into an array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the input file into an array or structs.

I'm not sure hot to navigate through the date portion separated by colons.

This question may be very broad and I'm open to any help.

This is my function:

```
void optionMammal (ifstream& inFile1)
{
    int mamNum;

    inFile1>>mamNum;
    mammal mamInfo [mamNum];

    initializeInfo(mamInfo, mamNum);

    for (int i=0; i<mamNum; i++)
    {

        inFile1>>mamInfo[i].species
               >>mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.month
               >>mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.day
               >>mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.year
               >>mamInfo[i].weight
               >>mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.length
               >>mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.width
               >>mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.height
               >>mamInfo[i].exhibit;

           cout<<mamInfo[i].species
               <<mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.month
               <<mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.day
               <<mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.year
               <<mamInfo[i].weight
               <<mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.length
               <<mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.width
               <<mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.height
               <<mamInfo[i].exhibit;
    }
}
```

And this is the input file.
The first number in the number or mammals in the file, and it should be a line above rhino.

```
15
Rhino 01:16:2000 5100 100:260:50 Africa
Lion 05:14:2006 420 150:64:55 Africa
Tapir 10:21:2015 550 90:50:30 Asia
Otter 09:08:2011 7 50:30:20 Americas
Fox 06:03:2013 6 30:25:34 Americas
Sheep 11:10:2004 200 50:50:20 Europe
Vole 12:06:2014 1 1:2:2 Europe
Cheetah 06:12:2003 80 30:30:20 Africa
Hedgehog 07:18:2006 1 2:2:3 Europe
Serval 08:22:2007 26 10:20:4 Africa
Shrew 08:23:2015 1 2:2:3 Europe
Bat 06:25:2016 2 6:7:15 Europe
Rabbit 04:23:2015 3 3:3:2 Europe
Seal 08:26:2014 200 50:50:20 Antartica
Dolphin 09:01:2017 330 200:200:60 Antartica
```

Answer (score 1):

Input is really not as simple as people prefer it to be. If there is a colon there, you should read it. Fortunately, your input makes life really, really easy.

First, you will need to expect a colon at the proper spots in your input, and fail if it is not there. Write an extractor for it and your Mammal extraction operator follows:

```
struct expect
{ 
  char c; 
  expect( char c ): c(c) { }
};

std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& ins, const expect& c )
{
  ins >> std::ws;
  if (ins.peek() == c.c) ins.get();
  else                   ins.setstate( std::ios::failbit );
  return ins;
}

std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& ins, Mammal& mammal )
{
  return ins 
    >> mammal.species
    >> mammal.dateOfBirth.month    >> expect( ':' )
    >> mammal.dateOfBirth.day      >> expect( ':' )
    >> mammal.dateOfBirth.year
    >> mammal.weight
    >> mammal.enclosureSize.length >> expect( ':' )
    >> mammal.enclosureSize.width  >> expect( ':' )
    >> mammal.enclosureSize.height
    >> mammal.exhibit;
}
```

Now you can just read a Mammal the normal way:

```
std::vector <Mammal> mammals;

int num_mammals;
std::cin >> num_mammals;

Mammal mammal;
while (std::cin >> mammal)
  mammals.push_back( mammal );
```

Or, using an array

```
Mammal mammals[ MAX_MAMMALS ];
int num_mammals = 0;

std::cin >> num_mammals;
if (num_mammals > MAX_MAMMALS) complain();

for (int n = 0; n < num_mammals; n++)
  std::cin >> mammals[ n ];
```

And so on.

Comment: This is the most efficient way. Well done I did not think of overloading the istream operator.  Beats the heck out of my rats nest of while loops!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first number in your file is the number of animals you have to parse. The rest of it is repetitive so I would just parse it in a while loop where whitespace delimits between variables.  When you get to the part that contains colons for your cage dimensions, just use a stringstream to break it up into individual parts.  Disclaimer: There are better ways to do this (exercise left to the reader) but this should give you the idea.

```
std::ifstream myfile("animals.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    int numberOfAnimals;
    myfile >> numberOfAnimals;
    std::string temp;
    while (myfile >> temp))
    {
        // string variables processed here
        // ...

        bool isNumber = (temp.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == std::string::npos);
        if (isNumber)
        {
            // use std::stoi() or std::stringstream to
            // convert actual number to int type
        }

        // logic to parse colon variables as needed here
        std::size_t found = temp.find_first_of(":");
        if (found > 0)
        {
            std::istringstream iss(temp);
            std::string token;
            while (std::getline(iss, token, ':'))
            {
                std::istringstream tss(token);
                int n;
                while (tss >> n)
                {
                    std::cout << n << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read the colon and forget it.

```
void optionMammal (ifstream& inFile1)
{
    int mamNum;

    inFile1>>mamNum;
    mammal mamInfo [mamNum];

    initializeInfo(mamInfo, mamNum);

    for (int i=0; i<mamNum; i++)
    {
        char colon;
        inFile1>>mamInfo[i].species
               >>mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.month >> colon
               >>mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.day >> colon
               >>mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.year
               >>mamInfo[i].weight
               >>mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.length >> colon
               >>mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.width >> colon
               >>mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.height
               >>mamInfo[i].exhibit;

           cout<<mamInfo[i].species
               <<mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.month
               <<mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.day
               <<mamInfo[i].dateOfBirth.year
               <<mamInfo[i].weight
               <<mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.length
               <<mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.width
               <<mamInfo[i].enclosureSize.height
               <<mamInfo[i].exhibit;
    }
}
```